# Read JSON Array that contains Arrays(?) C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I apologize in advance for the poor explanation of my problem.
I'm trying to read a JSON array that contains data.

Here's how the JSON looks:

```
{
    "playerstats": {
        "steamID": "76561198071680006",
        "gameName": "GameName",
        "achievements": [
            {
                "apiname": "AchievementName1",
                "achieved": 0, <--- Data that I want to read
                "unlocktime": 0
            },
            {
                "apiname": "AchievementName2",
                "achieved": 0, <--- Data that I want to read
                "unlocktime": 0
            },
            {
                "apiname": "AchievementName2",
                "achieved": 1, <--- Data that I want to read
                "unlocktime": 1477847680
            }
        ]
        ,
        "success": true
    }
}
```

I'm trying to look at Newtonsoft.Json and how to use that yet I'm at a complete loss as to how to use this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to read json data.

Having

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Playerstats playerstats { get; set; }
}

public class Playerstats
{
    public string steamID { get; set; }
    public string gameName { get; set; }
    public Achievement[] achievements { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class Achievement
{
    public string apiname { get; set; }
    public int achieved { get; set; }
    public int unlocktime { get; set; }
}
```

You can try this:

```
var filePath = path to your file;

var jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

Rootobject objectValue = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonData);
```

**Note:** you should remove `<--- Data that I want to read` parts from your json data because currently it is not a valid json format.

You may access to your desired properties like this

```
objectValue.playerstats.achievements[0].achieved //0
objectValue.playerstats.achievements[1].achieved //0
objectValue.playerstats.achievements[2].achieved //1
```